# How to annotate a Python3 method that returns self?

Tags: python-3.x, annotations, method-chaining

Function Annotations: [PEP-3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)

Background:  I am PyCharm user w/CPython 3.4x on Linux.  I find it helps to annotate function parameters and return types.  The IDE can better hint when I use these methods.

Question: For self-chaining methods, how can I annotate the method return value?  If I use the class name, Python throws an exception at compile time: `NameError: name 'X' is not defined`

Sample code:

```
class X:
    def yaya(self, x: int):
        # Do stuff here
        pass

    def chained_yaya(self, x: int) -> X:
        # Do stuff here
        return self
```

As a trick, if I put `X = None` just before the class declaration, it works.  However, I don't know if there are unforseen, negative side effects from this technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Python 3.11, you will be able to use `Self` to annotate the return type:

```py
from typing import Self


class X:
    def yaya(self, x: int):
        # Do stuff here
        pass

    def chained_yaya(self, x: int) -> Self:
        # Do stuff here
        return self
```

- [`PEP 673`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/)

Comment: Very nice update!  This is now the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
class X: 
    pass

class X:
    def yaya(self, x: int):
        # Do stuff here
        pass

    def chained_yaya(self, x: int) -> X:
        # Do stuff here
        return self
```

In your code, X has not been defined until the class definition is complete.

Same problem here: [putting current class as return type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853469/python-put-current-class-as-return-type-annotation)

His solution was to use a string. In your code that would be -> 'X'

Comment: String solution became the official one (as a result e.g. PyCharm fully supports it) - look here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references.