# Python annotations: refer to class?

Tags: python

I have a class method for getting a (search) Result from a Project. With Python's annotations, I don't know how to refer to the class the method is in (Result) without a NameError.

Here's an example:

```
class Project:
    pass

class Result:
    def from_project(project: Project) -> Result:
        pass
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15853469/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe can confirm, lemme flag my question. I *tried* finding it. Oh well.