# How can I refer to the currently being defined class?

Tags: python, class, python-decorators

How can I refer to the currently being defined class?

```
class A(object):
    # how can I use A here?
```

What I need to write is

```
class A(object):

    @some_decorator(A)
    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        pass
```

`some_decorator` registers an event listener that will trigger on some interaction with an `A` object. The `A` class itself needs to respond to these events in a way that interacts with private (`__` mangled) data.

Comment: Could you give some context? What would some_decorator be doing? Perhaps a metaclass would be more appropriate.

Comment: Please add more context to your question.

Comment: You can't.  This is a classic problem that has been discussed quite a bit (especially in the context of type annotations and checkers like mypy).  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Interesting. @mgilson why would someone want to refer to a class from inside the class? Keep in mind I only know python. I have not began to learn other languages yet.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech the example of type annotations would be e.g. a method that returns an instance of the class, but you can't do `def foo() -> A:` as `A` isn't bound yet - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853469/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for your example however after doing some reading I think this is a topic that I need to spend some time in as it is not something I am grasping easily. Would the method that returns an instance of the class need to be a method that is called from outside the class object? It does not seam like something that can be called during the `__init__` of the object creation and actually work.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech it doesn't matter. Could be a parameter instead of return value, with the method called from inside or outside of the class/instance. The type annotations are added *at class definition time*, before the class is created. And you *can* call instance, static and class methods from the same class's `__init__`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe well just goes to show the more I think I know about python the more I realize I have yet to learn. Time to spend another few days on a subject I am lacking in :D