# How do I annotate the type of __add__ (double underscore) method on a class?

Tags: python-3.x, types, mypy

I'm trying to annotate the `__add__` method of a class so that I can add instances of it together.  However, I'm unable to specify that this method takes another instance of the same type:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, v: int) -> None:
        self.v = v
    def __add__(self, other: Foo) -> Foo:
        return Foo(self.v + other.v)
```

However I seem to get an error regarding `Foo` not yet being defined, since it is referencing `Foo` within one of it's own method definitions

```
    def __add__(self, other: Foo) -> Foo:
NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

How can I annotate this correctly so that `mypy` warns me whenever there is code attempting to add instances of this class to instances of other classes?

Comment: Use `other: "Foo"`.  String literals in a type annotation have their evaluation deferred until later, when all of their forward references have been defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [putting current class as return type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853469/putting-current-class-as-return-type-annotation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I specify that the return type of a method is the same as the class itself in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-specify-that-the-return-type-of-a-method-is-the-same-as-the-class-itsel)

Answer (score 0):

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```